# How to replace deprecated okhttp.RequestBody.create()

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, image-upload

I try to upload an image from an Android App to a Django server using **Retrofit 2** and **OkHttp3**.
For that, I used to create a `RequestBody` instance using the following lines:

```
RequestBody requestImageFile =
                    // NOW this call is DEPRECATED
                    RequestBody.create(
                            MediaType.parse("image/*"),

                            // a File instance created via the path string to the image
                            imageFile
                    );
```

I used the previous instance in the next method call as argument:

```
// MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
MultipartBody.Part image = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", imageFile.getName(), requestImageFile);
```

Finally, I fired up the Retrofit interface to do the rest:

```
// finally, execute the request
Call<ResponseBody> call = service.upload(image);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.v("Upload", "success");
     }

     @Override
     public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Upload error:", t.getMessage());
     }
});
```

Some months ago, Android Studio did not told me that `create()` was deprecated. When I open the project now, it tells me that `create()` is deprecated. Does somebody know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Just swap the parameters from

```
RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), imageFile);
```

to

```
RequestBody.create(imageFile, MediaType.parse("image/*"));
```

Comment: Here is also a Kotlin solution:

1. `import okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.toRequestBody` in the import section of your Kotlin file. 
2. change code to `imageFile.asRequest("image/*")` for file type, or if you have some other content (string, for example), then use `content.toRequestType(mediaType)`

Comment: why they inverted the parameters...

Comment: This is strange/ weird ...but really cool as far as Shashanth's discovery is concerned.
Thanks a lot for the workaround.
it worked like a charm.

Comment: its not working imageFile.asRequest("image/*")

Answer (score 8):

You can use the Kotlin extensions as well.

```
val requestImageFile = imageFile.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is how to do it easily with kotlin extension functions from okhttp like:
**toRequestBody()**:

change from :

```
val requestImageFile = RequestBody.create(
                            MediaType.parse("image/*"),
                            imageFile
                    );
```

to this:

```
val requestImageFile = imageFile.toRequestBody(MediaType.parse("image/*"))
```

'
more info here: https://square.github.io/okhttp/upgrading_to_okhttp_4/

Answer (score 2):

You can change from:

```
RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), imageFile);
```

to:

```
RequestBody.Companion.create(imageFile, MediaType.parse("image/*"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
val responseBody: ResponseBody = body.toResponseBody("application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaType())
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?